# error when try to register Config in application on spring-mvc?

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat

Application on spring-mvc+ tomcat(without spring-boot)

There is project structure:
[image]

So, when I try to deploy war to local tomcat, there is error message

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/aspectj/lang/annotation/Around    at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.(ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.java:77)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.initBeanFactory(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:78)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.setBeanFactory(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:60)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1648)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1617)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
>     ... 56 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around    at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1291)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
>     ... 62 more

```
package init;

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @ComponentScan("com")
    public class WebAppInitalizer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
        @Override
        public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
            AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
            rootContext.register(
                    WebConfig.class);

            FilterRegistration charEncodingfilterReg = servletContext.addFilter("CharacterEncodingFilter", CharacterEncodingFilter.class);
            charEncodingfilterReg.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
            charEncodingfilterReg.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
            charEncodingfilterReg.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");

            servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

            ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
            dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
            dispatcher.addMapping("/*");
        }
    }
```

WebConfig

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com"})
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        converters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        RequestMappingHandlerMapping mhm = new RequestMappingHandlerMapping();
        //suffix parser is off for urls like .../search/timeKey.key:some_key
        mhm.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
        return mhm;
    }
}
```

and controller:

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/greeting", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String greeting() {
        return "greeting";
    }
}
```

applicationContext.xml and web.xml are empty.
So, error occurs when try to register WebConfig in WebAppInitializer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.16.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

fixed my issue.